# Why does Apache mod_perl build using APACI lose CFLAGS?

Tags: configuration, build, mod-perl

I am trying to build Apache 1.3.41 with mod_perl 1.31 for deployment to a Solaris 8 SPARC server. We must use 1.3 for now because of a number of essential applications currently deployed to a very large scale web site.

I am using the new(er) APACI technique as described in the [mod_perl install docs](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/install.html) but when I look at the compilation commands being issued to build the Apache part, the compile flags I've set using the CFLAGS options have been dropped.

The LDFLAGS appear to be passed through correctly though and both CFALGS and LDFLAGS are being exported.

Anyone else come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that that is the correct behaviour.

You want the modperl build to use the same options that were used to build your Perl install. So configure goes off and examines the relevant values returned after executing the command:

```
perl -V
```

this returns something like:

```
pc58: 876>perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.18-6-686, archname=i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
    uname='linux etch 2.6.18-6-686 #1 smp fri dec 12 16:48:28 utc 2008 i686 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dusethreads -Duselargefiles -Dccflags=-DDEBIAN -Dcccdlflags=-fPIC -Darchname=i486-linux-gnu -Dprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl/5.8 -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl/5.8 -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dvendorlib
=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5 -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8 -Dman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1 -Dman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3 -Dsitema
n1dir=/usr/local/man/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/usr/local/man/man3 -Dman1ext=1 -Dman3ext=3perl -Dpager=/usr/bin/sensible-pager -Uafs -Ud_csh -Ud_ualarm -Uusesfio -Uusenm -Duseshrplib -Dlibperl=libperl.so.5.8.8 -Dd_dosuid
 -des'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=define use5005threads=undef useithreads=define usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
    ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=4, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lgdbm -lgdbm_compat -ldb -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt
    libc=/lib/libc-2.3.6.so, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so.5.8.8
    gnulibc_version='2.3.6'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -L/usr/local/lib'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: MULTIPLICITY PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP THREADS_HAVE_PIDS USE_ITHREADS
                        USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Dec 18 2008 23:13:26
  @INC:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.8
    /usr/share/perl/5.8
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
pc58: 877>
```

configure then uses the ccflags and ldflags entries found.

cheers,